# Hosting email in another server

Tags: email-server

I'm considering to move my email to Rackspace, from my dedicated server which is also used for hosting. My question is, after I point out the mx records to Rackspace, if my dedicated server goes down, my email service will be affected? due to the Mx records unavailability?

Comment: If your mail server goes down most systems will queue the email and retry later for a few days.

Answer (score 3):

If your dedicated server is the authoritative Nameserver for your domain, then yes, after DNS caches expire email will break. Honestly, unless you have significant reasons for doing so, hosting your own DNS is a horrible idea, for this reason and many others.

Move to a third party DNS host and it won't be a problem. It will cost pennies, and will be much more reliable than anything you could possibly do on your own.